# PWA App on Mobile Safari Use Huge amount of cache?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have an angular PWA app run in iOS 12.4. we have one button for see the image of each user profile. when we open around 100 or 150 images then Setting --> Safari --> Advanced --> Website Data --> my app shown 150 MB storage !!! and rate as top one used data.

I should use caching for working PWA in offline mode, but how I can remove this storage or prevent image being cache by PWA on Mobile Safari ?

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "shell",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/vendor.*.js",
        "/main.*.js",
        "/polyfills.*.js",
        "/runtime.*.js",
        "/*.js",
        "/*.woff",
        "/*.ttf",
        "!/*-sw.js",
        "/*.json"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**",
        "/assets/images/**",
        "/profiles/**",
        "/*.(eot|svg|cur|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [{
    "name": "api",
    "version": 1,
    "urls": [
        "/api/**",
        "!/api/prescriptions/images/**",
        "!/**/*.*"
    ],
    "cacheConfig": {
      "strategy": "freshness",
      "maxSize": 1000,
      "maxAge": "7d",
      "timeout": "5s"
    }
  }]

}
```

Comment: I add the code but all images download with this flie.

Comment: Are you delivering your images via the `api/prescriptions/images` route?

Comment: @christianliebel yes.

Comment: @christianliebel is there any sample with angular app with that I can see for tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In `ngsw-config.json`, you are currently specifying a data group called `api`. Data groups are used to dynamically store HTTP(S) requests and their associated responses with content unrelated to the Angular app version (e.g. API requests). As a result, the responses are still available when the user is offline. As defined in the `urls` array, the data group is configured to cache all HTTP(S) requests/responses for the `/api/**` route.

Please note that [you can’t use negative glob patterns](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#datagroups) in data group `urls`, so neither the intended exclusion of the images route (`!api/prescriptions/images/**`) nor all files (`!**/*.*`) works. Consequently, all requests and responses to `/api/**` are cached—including the images.

If you don’t intend to cache API requests at all, simply remove the `api` data group:

```
"dataGroups": []
```

As a result, no dynamic caching will take place any longer (including images).

If you do want to cache certain API requests, you could use more specific URLs for the `app` data group that don’t include the images route:

```
"dataGroups": [{
  "name": "api",
  "version": 1,
  "urls": [
    "/api/prescriptions/*"
  ],
  // …
```

### Inspecting the Cache

For easier debugging, you can analyze the contents of the cache storage with the help of Chrome DevTools (Windows, Linux: <kbd>F12</kbd>, macOS:<kbd>⌥⌘I</kbd>) in the *Applications* tab. As of now, Safari does not have a Cache inspector, but the browsers should behave the same.

[image: Chrome DevTools Cache Inspector]

### Tutorials

As you’ve asked for tutorials, here are some suggestions:

- [the official documentation of Angular’s service worker implementation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro)
- [this blogpost by Angular University](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/)
- [my Angular PWA slide deck](https://speakerdeck.com/christianliebel/progressive-web-apps-mit-angular-das-web-wird-nativ-er-3ee1e5ae-aa20-466b-b362-a101daf26e77?slide=8)

Comment: one other tips is important, I need to my solution works offline too. with this tips this feature will be lost, isnt it?

Comment: @MokholiaPokholia Your application assets (specified in `assetGroups`) will still be available offline, so the app will run. As noted above, you could still choose to store data requests in the cache by including data routes, but excluding the images route. Alternatively, you could compress your images and/or reduce the `maxSize` of cache items to consume less space. However, please note that `dataGroups` are a dynamic caching method. The responses will only be available offline if they were previously requested. Also, sending requests (for manipulating data) won’t work offline.

Comment: @MokholiaPokholia That’s why I prefer to use IndexedDB for structured data, but this would introduce architectural changes to your application if you are currently relying on HTTP(S) requests. You might want to have a look at the following topics: offline-first, data synchronization, conflict resolution.